# CloudBees: Pipeline job: Will retention builds on condition match delete Permanent artifacts?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, ubuntu-18.04, cloudbees, retention

I have pipeline job in CloudBees which builds and uploads artifact on artifactory server. I have set **BuildRetention** Period. Using groovy script to run the job.

Command used is as follows:
        `buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 5, maxDays: 5, deleteBuildArtifacts: true`

Some builds are marked to retain as permanent.

E.g. Build retention period mentioned is for 5 builds and current job has 1 build marked as **KeepForever**

Need to know some information:
1. Will it delete the **KeepForever** build artifacts also?

Would like to know how will it work.

My requirement is when a build is run, it uploads to artifactory server with build retention. It should not delete builds marked with **KeepForever**

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be as simple as

```
currentBuild.rawBuild.keepLog(true)
```

It would have to be done for all the sub jobs as well if you have any.

Comment: This works fine if **Sandbox** is not enabled.  I need to run it in Sandbox mode.

Comment: Maybe you need to approve it in the script approval?

Comment: Cannot perform in automation as everytime it will run, we will need to approve.  
Any other alternate method?

Comment: There are two options there - approve every time or something like this should be one of those. So you would be able to just have it in your pipeline and use it.

Comment: I will not be able to approve every time as automation runs every night. I am looking for second option and that is my question i.e. What is the second option.